# Django UpdateView user validation not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Hello guys I have this update view where I am not able to validate the user(owner). How to tweak this to add that bit too.? Please have a look at the code.

```
class StoreInfoView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'store/store_information.html'
    form_class = StoreInfoForm
    success_message = 'Updated'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:store_home')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Store.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        if obj.user != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied('You Don\'t have permission to edit!')
        return obj

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Store.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object, form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say that the validation is not working, do you mean that any user is able to update the object?

Comment: yes..any user is able to edit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding like this, you can simply override `get_queryset()` method. Like this:

```
class StoreInfoView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'store/store_information.html'
    form_class = StoreInfoForm
    success_message = 'Updated'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:store_home')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

In this way, non-owner users will get 404 error when they try to update.

Also, you do not need to override any other methods like `get()` and `get_object()` method.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. but it doesn't work its showing this error
Generic detail view StoreInfoView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: are you not using with a pk or slug, like `path('storeinfo/<pk>/',StoreInfoView.as_view())` in urls?

Answer (score 0):

The issue to your problem is the order of inheritance. When you will go through the official docs for [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), you will find this

> This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list.

Please update your code to this

```
class StoreInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'store/store_information.html'
    form_class = StoreInfoForm
    success_message = 'Updated'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:store_home')

    ...
```

Notice, now `LoginRequiredMixin` is put before the `UpdateView`. This should resolve your query.

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't work, its the same anyone can edit the post

Comment: I see, can you also tell if it is at least not allowing the non-login user.? I mean if a user is not logged in, then is it able to detect that?

Comment: No he can't access that page. I tried that just now. :)